# About php date format

Tags: php, date, datetime

My current date format is

```
15/May/2015
```

I want to get it as

```
05/15/2015
```

Please help me about this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php

Comment: This should help: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given that you have some sort of timestamp already, you can do this:

```
$date = date('m/d/Y', $timestamp);
```

If you don't have a timestamp, let's assume you have your current date stored in a variable:

```
$original = '15/May/2015';
```

You can then do this:

```
$date = date('m/d/Y', strtotime($original));
```

Alternatively, you can use the `DateTime` class:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/M/Y', $original)->format('m/d/Y');
// Assumed 'd/M/Y' as current format  ^
// Could also be 'j/M/Y', 'd/F/Y', 'j/F/Y', etc.
```

For more info, check the docs for [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php), [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php), and [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the current date in that format, simply use:

```
$now = date("m/d/Y");
```

But the docs are your friend: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php